# php imagejpeg() function breaks png images

Tags: php

I have a `php` function named `compressImage()` that looks like:

```
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);


    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
      $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

  }
```

I am trying to compress uploaded images using this function. In a `php` file named `add1.php` I call this function like this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image1']['name'])) {

    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
    $newName = date('Ymdhis')."1";
    $newName = strval($newName) . "." . end($temp);
    $newPath = '../uploads/'.$newName;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $target_dir . $newName);
    compressImage($newPath, $newPath, 60);
    $image1 = $newName;

}
```

And this works when I upload `jpeg` images and it actually reduces their size. But when I upload `png` files they are uploaded but are broken and cannot be opened. I do not have any idea what the cause of this problem is. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the `compressImage` so that it generates images in the same format as they are supplied and use the return value from the function for further processing if required.

```
function compressImage( $source=false, $destination=false, $quality=80, $filters=false ) {
    $info = getimagesize( $source );
    switch( $info['mime'] ){
        case 'image/jpeg':
            /* Quality: integer 0 - 100 */
            if( !is_int( $quality ) or $quality < 0 or $quality > 100 ) $quality=80;
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $source );
            return imagejpeg( $image, $destination, $quality );

        case 'image/gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif( $source );
            return imagegif( $image, $destination );

        case 'image/png':
            /* Quality: Compression integer 0(none) - 9(max) */
            if( !is_int( $quality ) or $quality < 0 or $quality > 9 )$quality=6;
            $image = imagecreatefrompng( $source );
            return imagepng( $image, $destination, $quality, $filters );

        case 'image/webp':
            /* Quality: Compression 0(lowest) - 100(highest) */
            if( !is_int( $quality ) or $quality < 0 or $quality > 100 )$quality=80;
            $image=imagecreatefromwebp( $source );
            return imagewebp( $image, $destination, $quality );

        case 'image/bmp':
            /* Quality: Boolean for compression */
            if( !is_bool( $quality ) )$quality=true;
            $image=imagecreatefrombmp( $source );
            return imagebmp( $image, $destination, $quality );

        default:exit( sprintf( 'Unknown type: %s',$info['mime'] ) );
    }
}
```

Using the return value

```
if( compressImage($newPath, $newPath, 60) ){ /* success */ }
else { /* Failure */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

In all cases you are writing the image using `imagejpeg`; also the GIF and PNG files.